# why django inlineformset_factory data not saving in class-based updateview?

Tags: django

inlineformset_factory fields is rendering in my html template. Others fields data saving except inlineformset_factory fields. here is my code:

**models.py**

```
class HeaderImage(models.Model):
      header_image = models.ImageField()
      post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**froms.py**

```
BlogImageFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Post,  # parent form
                                                  HeaderImage,  # inline-form

                                                fields=['header_image'] ,can_delete=False, extra=1)
```

**#views.py**

```
class BlogUpdateView(PermissionRequiredMixin,UpdateView):
      raise_exception = True
      permission_required = "blog.change_post"
      model = Post
      template_name = "blog_update_post.html"
      form_class = BlogPost

      def get_success_url(self):
        self.success_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog'
        return self.success_url
                   
      def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BlogUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            context['form'] = BlogPost(self.request.POST, instance=self.object)
            context['ingredient_form'] = BlogImageFormSet(self.request.POST, instance=self.object)
            
        else:
            context['form'] = BlogPost(instance=self.object)
            context['ingredient_form'] =BlogImageFormSet(instance=self.object)
        return context
      

      def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        ingredient_form = BlogImageFormSet(self.request.POST)
        if (form.is_valid() and ingredient_form.is_valid()):
            return self.form_valid(form, ingredient_form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form, ingredient_form)


      def form_valid(self, form, ingredient_form):
        self.object = form.save()
        ingredient_form.instance = self.object
        ingredient_form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
      

      def form_invalid(self, form, ingredient_form):
        return self.render_to_response(
            self.get_context_data(form=form,
                                  ingredient_form=ingredient_form,
                                 ))
```

**#html**

```
   <form method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
    
    {% csrf_token %}
    
    {{form.media}}
    {{form.as_p}}
    {{ingredient_form}}
    <button class="btn btn-info">Update</button>
</form>
```

I am not understanding why data is not saving for inlineformset_factory field. see the picture for better understand
[image]

Comment: hello, can you show your template?

Comment: @DiegoPuente   sure. I updated my question. please see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
class BlogUpdateView(PermissionRequiredMixin,UpdateView):
    ...

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BlogUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            context['form'] = BlogPost(self.request.POST, instance=self.object)
            # this line below changed
            context['ingredient_form'] = BlogImageFormSet(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES, instance=self.object)
            
        else:
            context['form'] = BlogPost(instance=self.object)
            context['ingredient_form'] =BlogImageFormSet(instance=self.object)
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        # this line below changed
        ingredient_form = BlogImageFormSet(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES)
        if (form.is_valid() and ingredient_form.is_valid()):
            return self.form_valid(form, ingredient_form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form, ingredient_form)
    ...
```

Comment: Diego Puente I also tried this method but didn't work. getting this error `form_valid() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`

Comment: did you add `self.request.FILES` to your formsets?

Comment: @ Diego Puente yes I added

Comment: did you remove your method override of form_valid? because the tree dots on my answer(on top and bottom) means that you only have to change the code that I put there and keep the rest same.

Comment: Diego Puente yeah  I  override of form_valid but still now not saving the data

Comment: Diego Puente  Thanks Your code worked now. After add `self.request.FILES` it worked

Answer (score 1):

by data you mean the file you are uploading is not getting saved. The image field in your model needs a location to save the file

header_image = models.ImageField(**upload_to='some_directory/**')

Comment: did you update the settings.py also , with MEDIA_URL?

Comment: Hi Thanks..my problem solved after follow Diego Puente  instruction

Comment: I was missing `self.request.FILES` as tried to upload fields.